# How can I draw with a pencil using BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

Right now I only have this code, but I'm not using `BitmapData.draw()`. How can I write my code using `BitmapData.draw()`?

```
penSprite.graphics.lineStyle(3,045666);

addChild(penSprite);

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   mouseUp);

penSprite = new Sprite();                  //var penSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mouseDownFlag = new Boolean();            //var mouseDownFlag:Boolean = false;

private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    penSprite.graphics.moveTo(e.localX, e.localY);
    mouseDownFlag = true;
}

private function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (mouseDownFlag) penSprite.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);
}

private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mouseDownFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I want to draw with my mouse or a pen using bitmapData.Draw(), in he code abow Im not using bitmapData.Draw().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code sample based on you code. You try it out by just making it a base class of the movie.

```
package {
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/**
 * Drawing app
 */
public class DrawingApp extends MovieClip {

    /** Drawing sprite */
    protected var penSprite     : Sprite = new Sprite();

    /** Bitmap where drawing will be saved */
    protected var canvasBitmap  : Bitmap;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function DrawingApp () {

        // create bitmap that hold a bitmap data, where your drawing will displayed
        this.canvasBitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight ), "auto", true );

        // add children. Canvas must be below sprite
        this.addChild( canvasBitmap );
        this.addChild(penSprite);

        this.penSprite.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000 );

        // listen to stage, not to the root or you won't get mouse down events root sprite is empty.
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.mouseDown);

    }

    /**
     * Start drawing 
     */
    private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {

        this.penSprite.graphics.moveTo(e.localX, e.localY);

        // add movement listeners here instead of using flag
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.mouseMove);
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   this.mouseUp);

    }

    /**
     * Draw line on sprite
     */
    private function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
        penSprite.graphics.lineTo( e.localX, e.localY );
    }

    /**
     * Draw sprite graphics to canvas and end drawing by cleaning up sprite graphics and unregistering movement listeners
     */
    private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {

        // draw sprite graphics to bitmap data (last parameter makes drawing smooth)
        canvasBitmap.bitmapData.draw( penSprite, null, null, null, null, true );

        // remove listeners 
        this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
        this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   mouseUp);

    }           

}
```

}

Comment: Ok, I have try it now and I get this error:                           TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at DrawingApp()[/Users/VVT/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/SuperDraw/src/DrawingApp.as:25]
 at SuperDraw()[/Users/VVT/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/SuperDraw/src/SuperDraw.as:59]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your question is not very clear, I suppose that you want to copy your content in a Bitmap.
If this is what you want to accomplish, just create a new bitmapData, draw your sprite in it and use it as a source of a Bitmap.
For example, when you finish to draw in your penSprite, you can copy it in a Bitmap like this:

```
 var bData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(penSprite.width, penSprite.height,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
 bData.draw(penSprite);
 var image:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bData);
 addChild(image);
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

EDIT:
I see that you just add a comment in your question, saying that you want to draw "using bitmapData.draw". So, I think you are misunderstanding the use of that method. If you look in the documentation:

"Draws the source display object onto the bitmap image, using the Flash runtime vector renderer. "

So you basically use it to draw another display object in a bitmapData.

Comment: `.bitmapData.draw()` is to essential rasterize a flash display object onto a bitmap surface. You *could* use `.setPixel()` to draw directly to a bitmap, probably using something like  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm